# command to watch incoming server connections as they happen

Tags: sockets, connection, ports

I enter this on the unix command line:

```
netstat -anpt | grep -v LISTEN
```

I am able to see what addresses connect to services on my server, however I want to see this updated at one-second intervals so I can get some sort of idea as to who is connecting to what and when.

When I attempt to execute:

```
watch -n 1 netstat -anpt | grep -v LISTEN
```

The screen does nothing, and I have to press CTRL+C in order to exit.

If however, I execute:

```
watch -n 1 netstat -anpt
```

The exhaustive list appears and the watch program executes, however I don't want to see all the sockets in only the listening state (which is why I appended `| grep -v LISTEN` to the command-line).

What command do I use?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to see all the sockets in only the listening state

Then simply don't tell `netstat` to

> **-a, --all**
>          Show both listening and non-listening sockets.

Use just options `-npt`.